# Android Wear 2.0 can you still synch "dnd" with phone?

Tags: android-wear

The standard behavior before android wear 2.0 was that when I put the watch on DND my phone would go on DND too. That was precisely what I wanted. But now with AW2.0 they appear to be separate. Anyone know if I can change that back?